# Сброс нумерации элементов в массиве jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив нумерация элементов от 20-39.
Как можно сбросить нумерацию элементов в массиве,
чтобы она стала от 0-19?

```
20: (3) ["image21.jpg", "Вопрос 21", Array(2)]
21: (3) ["image22.jpg", "Вопрос 22", Array(3)]
22: (3) ["image23.jpg", "Вопрос 23", Array(3)]
23: (3) ["image24.jpg", "Вопрос 24", Array(2)]
24: (3) ["image25.jpg", "Вопрос 25", Array(2)]
25: (3) ["image26.jpg", "Вопрос 26", Array(2)]
26: (3) ["image27.jpg", "Вопрос 27", Array(2)]
27: (3) ["image28.jpg", "Вопрос 28", Array(2)]
28: (3) ["image29.jpg", "Вопрос 29", Array(2)]
29: (3) ["image30.jpg", "Вопрос 30", Array(2)]
30: (3) ["image31.jpg", "Вопрос 31", Array(2)]
31: (3) ["image32.jpg", "Вопрос 32", Array(2)]
32: (3) ["image33.jpg", "Вопрос 33", Array(2)]
33: (3) ["image34.jpg", "Вопрос 34", Array(2)]
34: (3) ["image35.jpg", "Вопрос 35", Array(2)]
35: (3) ["image36.jpg", "Вопрос 36", Array(2)]
36: (3) ["image37.jpg", "Вопрос 37", Array(2)]
37: (3) ["image38.jpg", "Вопрос 38", Array(2)]
38: (3) ["image39.jpg", "Вопрос 39", Array(2)]
39: (3) ["image40.jpg", "Вопрос 40", Array(2)]
```

Comment: Или я чего-то не знаю, или это скопированный кусок какого-то лога... И невозможно дать ответ, не зная, что это за кусок и откуда приходит...

Comment: Да, это кусок лога, но вопрос от этого не меняется) Можно на него даже не смотреть. Мне интересна сама суть вопроса.

Comment: Потому что вдруг https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/49hzs10p/ ... массивом в JS называют то, что `var array = ['внутри', 'квадратных', 'скобок'];` ... а то, что перед ними стоит - просто нумерация... Её по разному можно делать)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нашел интересный способ (просто перезаписать в новый массив)

```
function convert(obj) {
    var z = [];

    for (var prop in obj) {
        z.push(obj[prop]);
    }

    return z;
}
```

В качестве параметра передаем массив, у которого нужно сбросить нумерацию

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас так называемый ассоциативный массив(в JS - это просто объект), то можно использовать метод `Object.values`, чтобы превратить его в обычный массив:

```js
const list = {
  20: ['Двадцать', [2, 0]],
  21: ['Двадцать один', [2, 1]],
}
const arr = Object.values(list);
console.log(0, arr[0]);
console.log(1, arr[1]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Вам необходимо использовать метод [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const arr = Array(40)
for (let i = 20; i < 40; i++) {
  arr[i] = `image${i + 1}.jpg`
}

console.log(arr.filter(v => v != undefined))
```